# How to explain calm period in energy consumption

Tags: time-series, forecast

I have a dataset of energy consumption that looks like this:

[image: Time series]

I got it from [Kaggle.com](https://www.kaggle.com/robikscube/hourly-energy-consumption/version/3#pjm_hourly_est.csv) and all it says is that it's energy consumption data from PJM (this is the PJMW_hourly that corresponds to the western zone, but they are all similar).

I studied and fitted models on the five weeks (April 18 to May 22, 2016) between the two blue lines on the picture.

I fitted a SARIMA (not that it matters for this question) and it obviously didn't predict that the series was going to blow up like it does.

So I was wondering if this kind of behavior can be explained by weather or the price of coal or anything like that?

Thanks

Comment: Find historical hourly temperature and coal price data, then do regression analysis. Wouldn't that give you an answer?

Comment: do you mean ARIMA? what is the S. Would help to see what the „real“ time (x axis) is.

Comment: @Boondoggle that's an idea, I looked at weather... There does not seem to be any link at first sight (it would be off topic to run models on weather or coal price, it's just a time series assignment)

Comment: @Peter Yes ARIMA with seasonality = 168 hours (=1 week). It's hourly data with weekly and daily seasonality. The region is April 18 to May 22, it consists of 5 weeks